# Writing random values from function to generated table using JS?

Tags: javascript, html, html-table

I have a table that generates 5 columns and X rows based on an input by the user. In the rows I am trying to generate random numbers to simulate data. Currently my content for the table is generated by this JS for loop:

```
for(i = dur; i >= 0; i -= 15)
    {
           document.write('<tr>')
           document.write('<td>reading ' + i + ', column 0;</td>')
           document.write('<td>reading ' + i + ', column 1</td>')
           document.write('<td>reading ' + i + ', column 2</td>')
           document.write('<td>reading ' + i + ', column 3</td>')
           document.write('<td>reading ' + i + ', column 4</td>')
           document.write('</tr>')  
    }
```

I have a function that creates random numbers with 2 decimal places as long as the min and max are >10k and <99k:

```
function randomNumber (min, max) 
    {
        var random =  Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min) + min))/100;
    }
```

What I want to happen is during the for loop insert randomly created numbers using the function instead of my i value that is currently there as a place holder.

EDIT: I would also like to be able to manipulate the data within the table. I.E. column 3 = column 1 + column2.

Comment: [SOLVED]

I changed the function to return instead of set its own variable:

    function randomNumber (min, max) 
 {
     return Math.floor((Math.random() * (max - min) + min))/100;
 }

I added this line to the top of the loop:

    var j = randomNumber(23800,24200);

I then changed the appropriate column to call the j variable:

    document.write('<td>reading ' + j + ', column 1</td>')

Comment: There was an answer on here that helped. It has since been deleted. I wish I could give you some credit whoever posted.

Answer (score 0):

One another solution I tried here:

```html
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Page Title</title>
            <style>
                td {
                    border: 1px solid #000;
                    padding: 20px;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                var table = document.createElement('table');
                for(let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
                    var tr = document.createElement('tr');
                    for(let j = 0; j < 5; j++) {
                        var td = document.createElement('td');
                        td.innerHTML = Math.floor((Math.random()*100) + 1);
                        tr.appendChild(td)
                    }
                    table.appendChild(tr)
                }
                document.body.appendChild(table)
            </script>
        </body>
    </html>
```